# An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine C# error connect to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows-services

I programmed a Windows service which gets strings from a client using TCP socket and saves them to a database. It's connect and no have error send/receive. But in first, service can't connect to SQL Server database :

```
string sql = "Select * from [Commands] Where [cName]='" + _cName + "'";
pr = new Persistance();

using (var item = pr.sqlDataReader(sql))
{
    return new Commands
    {
                    cID = item.GetInt32(0),
                    cName = item.GetString(1),
                    cType = item.GetInt32(2),
                    msgID = item.GetInt32(3)
    };
}
```

My persistance class;

```
public SqlDataReader sqlDataReader(string sqlCommand)
{
    connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    return new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, connection).ExecuteReader();
}
```

What I miss I can't understand. it write in catch side :

> An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: are you sure that your connection string is proper?

Comment: Check your sql server audit logs. If this were me I'd ditch the sqldatareader public function. Given it's a service, I'd be making it much more robust as well, usings, try catch exceptions to a log file etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use **parametrized queries** to avoid SQL injection attacks - so you'll need to modify your `SELECT` statement:

```
string sql = "Select * from [Commands] Where [cName]= @cname";
```

and you'll need to somehow define that parameter and set its value - not sure what your `Persistance` class is that you're using - in raw ADO.NET, it would be something like:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@cname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = _cName;
```

Next, when using a `SqlDataReader`, you must call `.Read()` on that data reader to actually get the data:

```
using (var item = pr.sqlDataReader(sql))
{ 
    // call .Read() on the SqlDataReader - and this *COULD* return multiple rows! 
    // Not just one - it could return many - so you'll need to handle that somehow.....
    while (item.Read()) 
    {
       Commands cmd = new Commands
                         {
                           cID = item.GetInt32(0),
                           cName = item.GetString(1),
                           cType = item.GetInt32(2),
                           msgID = item.GetInt32(3)
                       };
       // store all those "Commands" retrieved into a list or something and return them
    }
}
```